# is the assumption If X⊥⊥Y | Z and X⊥⊥Y then (X⊥⊥Z or Y ⊥⊥Z) true?

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayesian-network, probabilistic-method

is the assumption If X⊥⊥Y | Z and X⊥⊥Y then (X⊥⊥Z or Y ⊥⊥Z) true ?

where X⊥⊥Y means is independent of Y and X⊥⊥Y means that X is independent of Y given Z?

I have been trying to prove or disprove the assumption above , but I neither found a proof or a counter exemple.

so far I got that expression $p(z|x,y) = \frac{p(z|x)p(z|y)}{p(z)}$ , but I don't really know how I can use it to prove or disprove.

now I try to find real table and show that that des not hold every time, but I'm stuck...

can anyone give me some help with that question ? (Z is a binary random variable)

Comment: In the title are two notations, one is two upside down T's next to each other, the other is a vertical bar. Please define these notations in your question. Also the question should be in the body not just in title.

Comment: One more issue: both the double rotated T and the bar are presumably binary operations. Your first assumption has both of them so needs a pair of parentheses to dictate how to do both operations.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, it solves the problem when Z is not a binary random variable thanks ! , but when you say that A,B, C are events instead of random variables, can I consider that it's binary random variable where A=1(same for B and C) when the corresponding event happens ?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3631/is-there-a-standard-symbol-for-conditional-independence

Comment: @mproboss My answer to the duplicate question also deals with the case where the three things are events.